# Should I mock all the direct dependencies of a class in unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing

Let's say that we have a class `Controller` that depends on a class `Service`, and the `Service` class depends on a class `Repository`. Only `Repository` communicates with an external system (say DB) and I know it should be mocked when unit testing is executed.

My question: For unit tests, should I mock the `Service` class when `Controller` class is tested even though the `Service` class doesn't depend on any external systems directly? and Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the kind of test you are writing: integration test or unit test.
I assume you want to write a unit test in this case. The purpose of a unit test is to solely test the business logic of your class so every other dependency should be mocked.

In this case you will mock the `Service` class. Doing so also allows you to prepare for testing certain scenarios based on the input you are passing to a certain method of `Service`. Imagine you have a `Person findPerson(Long personID)`-method in your `Service`. When testing your `Controller` you are not interested in doing everything that's necessary for having `Service` actually return the right output. For a certain test scenario for your `Controller` you just want it to return a `Person` whereas for a different test scenario you don't want it to return anything. Mocking makes this very easy.

Also note that if you mock your `Service` you don't have to mock `Repository` since your `Service` is already a mock.

TLDR; When writing a unit test for a certain class, just mock every other dependency to be able to manipulate the output of method invocations made to these dependencies.

Comment: Your assumption was right: I'd like to write unit tests. And now I've got how unit tests should be. Thank you very much!

Comment: Mocking every dependency is going too far. This will cause your tests to become tightly coupled with implementation details. What you want is to mock (or fake) so called volatile dependencies which are hard to control. These are dependencies that do things like IO or depend on the system timer.
If you mock everything you are going to have to change all your tests every time you refactor even if you don't change behavior.

Answer (score 1):

As with all engineering questions, TDD is no different. The answer always is, "it depends". There's always trade offs.

In the case of TDD, you develop the test through behavioral expectations first. In my experiences, a behavioral expectation is a unit.

An example, say you want to get all users that start with the last name 'A', and they are active in the system. So you would write a test to create a controller action to get active users that start with 'A' `public ActionResult GetAllActiveUsersThatStartWithA()`.

In the end, I might have something like this:

```
public ActionResultGetAllActiveUsersThatStartWithA()
{
    var users = _repository.GetAllUsers();
    var activeUsersThatStartWithA = users.Where(u => u.IsActive && u.Name.StartsWith('A');
    return View(activeUsersThatStartWithA);
}
```

This to me is a unit. I can then now refactor (change me implementation without changing behavior by adding a `service` class with the method below)

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetActiveUsersThatStartWithLetter(char startWith)
{
    var users = _repository.GetAllUsers();
    var activeUsersThatStartWithA = users.Where(u => u.IsActive && u.Name.StartsWith(startsWith);
}
```

And my new implementation of the controller becomes

```
public ActionResultGetAllActiveUsersThatStartWithA()
{
    return View(_service.GetActiveUsersThatStartWithLetter('A');
}
```

This is obviously a very contrived example, but it gives an idea of my point. The main benefit of doing it this way is that my tests aren't tied to any implementations details except the `repository`. Whereas, if I mocked out the `service` in my tests, I am now tied to that implementation. If for whatever reason that `service` layer is removed, all my tests break. I would find it more likely that the `service` layer is more volatile to change than the `repository` layer.

The other thing to think about is if I do mock out `service` in my controller class, I could run into a scenario where all my tests are working properly, but the only way I find out the system is broken is through an integration test (meaning that out of process, or assembly components interact with each other), or through production issues.

If for instance I change the implementation of the `service` class to below:

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetActiveUsersThatStartWithLetter(char startsWith)
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Again, this is a very contrived example, but the point is still relevant. I would not catch this with my `controller` tests, hence it looks like the system is behaving properly with my passing "unit tests", but in reality the system is not working at all.

The downside with my approach is that the tests could become very cumbersome to setup. So the tradeoff is balancing out test complexity with abstraction/mockable implementations.

Key thing to keep in mind is that TDD gives the benefit of catching regressions, but it's main benefit to is to help design a system. In other words, don't let the design dictate the tests you write. Let the tests dictate the functionality of the system first, then worry about the design through refactoring.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, mock Services when testing controllers. Unit tests help to identify the location of a regression. So a Test for a Service code should only fail if the service code has changed, not if the controller code has changed. That way, when the service test fails, you know for sure that the root cause lies in a change to Service.

Also, usually it is much easier to mock the service than to mock all repositories invoked by the service just to test the controller. So it makes your tests easier to maintain.

But in general, you may keep certain util classes unmocked, as you loose more than you gain by mocking those. Also see:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148049/how-to-deal-with-static-utility-classes-when-designing-for-testability